# Support scripting in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to use C# as a scripting language? I want users to be able to write a method body and work with objects that are passed from the main program to the script method.

And maybe is there something more universal out there? So I can support more than C#?

Comment: but I read its not ready for production use

Comment: I would say your best bet would be [Powershell](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-fundamental-concepts-for-powershell-scripting/2146), which you can automate from C#. Roslyn certainly look interesting though!

Comment: Why not use a language that was designed to be a scripting langauge instead of one that wasn't?  A large number of it's design decisions make it a great language for large scale programs, but those same design decisions make it much clunkier and harder to use in a scripting context.  Scripting language aren't better or worse, they're just designed to fill a different role.  If that's the role you need filled, use the proper language for the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [scriptcs](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs). Scott Hanselman has a great blog post about it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ProjectlessScriptedCWithScriptCSAndRoslyn.aspx). It allows you to do scripting with C#, either by running arbitrary scripts as [*.csx files](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Writing-a-script), written with with your favorite text editor or by using the [REPL](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/REPL). It also has integration with NuGet to allow you to easily pull down dependencies.

The [`ScriptCs.Core`](http://nuget.org/packages/ScriptCs.Core) library can be used to host script execution in your own application, like [OctopusDeploy has done](http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/octopus-1.5-azure-ftp-scriptcs).

The scripting engine is pluggable. As of now, it uses Roslyn as the C# scripting engine, but there's also work being done to use mono as an alternative. There's nothing stopping you from implementing f.ex. [F# support](https://twitter.com/7sharp9/status/346044794319015936).

To make bootstrapping of popular frameworks even easier, there's [script packs](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Script-Packs-master-list) that reduces the amount of code you have to write to get something running quickly.

To get you started, check out the [samples repository](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs-samples).